# How to select areas from a target layer which do not intersect source layer?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, select, select-by-attribute

I have two different layers, one is county boundary and another one is soil map.

My question is I would like to select only those areas which are outside the county boundary.

Using "**Select by location**" I can select every polygon located inside the county boundary but it is not what I need, I need **only the unselected polygons**.

What should I do?

I am using Arcmap 10.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Please always include the software product and version that you are using - it helps us help you.

Comment: In the attribute table, you will see your selected rows.  There is a button to switch selection.  Press it and that will be your desired result.